# How to access the matched value in the default case of pattern matching?

Tags: rust

the question is about the default case.

Let's consider the following code:

```
fn func(x: i64) {
  match x {
    0 => println!("Zero"),
    1 => println!("One"),
    _ => {
      //How to get the value here not via repeating the matched expression ?
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to repeat the expression because it's more complex than just a variable, you can bind it to a variable:

```
fn func(x: i64) {
  match <some complex expression> {
    0 => println!("Zero"),
    1 => println!("One"),
    y => {
      // you can use y here
    }
  };
}
```

This also works as a default case, because a variable pattern matches everything just like `_` does.

`_` is useful exactly when you don't want to use the value.

Comment: To clarify, `_` is not a special pattern. The "match any other value here" is done using binding pattern, and that binding is what can be the "don't care about actual value", which is `_`.

Comment: Also note that `y` results in the value being _moved_ into `y`, whereas `_` means the value is simply ignored. If you want to avoid the move, you can use the pattern `ref y` to create a reference to the value instead.

Comment: @Sahsahae `_` is kind of special, because you can't use it to bind a value, only to ignore one. But you're right, it's not special to `match`.

Comment: I meant in terms of patterns. The asker seems to think that `_` itself means "other", hence why question exists in the first place.